# Move Nested SVN Repository

Tags: svn, batch-file, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I need to move a SVN repository from one server to another in Windows. The trick is that I want to exclude everything except the trunk, branches, and tags from a project within a nested repository.

I currently have one large repository that all the projects are under (MyBigRepo). The current structure is:

```
/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject1/trunk
/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject1/branches
/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject1/tags

/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject2/trunk
/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject2/branches
/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject2/tags

/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject3/trunk
/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject3/branches
/Repositories/MyBigRepo/MyProject3/tags
```

I only want to move `MyProject1`, but I want to *exclude* the main folder `MyProject1` and just move trunk, branches, and tags from the `MyProject1` repository. I *don't* want to move `MyProject2` or `MyProject3`. In other words, my *goal* is to form my new repository similar to below.

```
/Repositories/NewRepo/trunk
/Repositories/NewRepo/branches
/Repositories/NewRepo/tags
```

Here's the batch file I created to do the work:

```
:: Create a dump of the old repo
svnadmin dump %OldRepoPath% > %MyBigRepoDumpFile%

:: Remove the other projects
svndumpfilter include "MyProject1" < %MyBigRepoDumpFile% > %MyProject1DumpFile%

:: Create a new repo
svnadmin create %NewRepoPath%

:: Load the dump into the new repo
svnadmin load %NewRepoPath% < %MyProject1DumpFile%
```

My problem is that the batch still creates the MyProject1 directory under the `%NewRepoPath%` like this:

```
/Repositories/NewRepo/MyProject1/trunk
/Repositories/NewRepo/MyProject1/branches
/Repositories/NewRepo/MyProject1/tags
```

Is there a way to either exclude the extra level (MyProject1) from my dump file or move it up a level, still preserving the history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to move it "as is" (with the extra level present) and then redo the structure via `svn copy` in the new repository.

There is also an option of tweaking you dumpfile [as described here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the svndumpfilter twice:

1. Filter out the "/Repositories/NewRepo/MyProject1/" path (as you've already done),
2. Filter out the 'trunk', 'branches' and 'tags'.

Comment: There is a rather nasty technical problem with this approach: trunk, branches, and tags for the same project are usually so interwoven together that svndumpfilter won't be able to separate them. I tried to do something similar once - wasted couple of days and gave up in the end.

Comment: When I run `svndumpfilter include "trunk" "branches" "tags" < %MyProject1DumpFile% > %MyProject1DumpFile%`, I get an empty dump file. Do you know why this might be?